# Java Concept Confusion : Objects and Primitive Types

Tags: object, methods, reference, primitive

I am really confused about this concept:

```
/* Example with primitive data type */

public class Example1 {

public static void main (String[] args){
int a = 1;

System.out.println("a is " + a);
myMethod( a );
System.out.println("a is " + a);

}

public static void myMethod(int b){

b = 3;
System.out.println("b is " + b);

    }
}
```

OUTPUT:

a is 1

b is 3

a is 1

Why does "a" not change?How does this primitive variable CHANGE like for a FOR LOOP or a WHILE LOOP when int i is initialed to zero? Like this:

```
int i = 1;
while (i < = 3) {
 System.out.println(i);
 i *= 2;
}
```

OUTPUT:

1

2

Please let me know in detail, as I am really confused.i is a primitive type, why does it get updated, and why does not int a in the first program?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"*Why does "a" not change?*"

Because primitive `a` inside of your `myMethod` is not the same `a` that you had in your `void main`. Treat it as completely another variable and that its value got copied into `myMethod`. This primitive`s lifecycle ends in the end of this method execution.

**If you have C++ background** then maybe this explanation might help:

- When you pass primitive type arguments into method - you are passing
  variables that are being copied. You passed value, not instance.
- When you pass objects as arguments
  into method - you are passing references to that object, **but** to be more precise: in java, a copy of reference value is being passed. It is like passing a copy of the address of the object to the method. If you modify this object inside this method, the modifications will be visible outside the method. If you `=null` or `=new Obj` it, it will affect the object only inside your method.

Comment: Perfect, I could have voted you up , but I could not because I have a low repetition.

Answer (score 1):

myMethod() is void, if it returned an int and you assigned a=myMethod(a) then it would change

```
int a = 1;
System.out.println("a is " + a);
a= myMethod(a); //where myMethod is changed to return b instead of void
System.out.println("a is " + a);
```

a is 1

b is 3

a is 3